# sorting a dictionary by key?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort a dictionary by it's key, since WP7 does not support `SortedDictionary`. How can I do it nice, easy and optimal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Dictionary in place with respect to keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("3", "three");
dict.Add("1", "one");
dict.Add("2", "two");

var sortedDict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Key ascending select entry); 

foreach (var k in sortedDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key:{0}, val={1} ", k.Key, k.Value);
}
```

This works, but sortedDict is not a dictionary. I solved it:

```
sortedDict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Key ascending select entry)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: solved it: dict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Key ascending select entry).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);

Answer (score 1):

This stack overflow question includes a solution using LINQ.

[How do you sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289/how-do-you-sort-a-c-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: i tried this code:

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dict.Add("3", "three");
            dict.Add("1", "one");
            dict.Add("2", "two");

            var sortedDict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Key ascending select entry); 

This works, but sortedDict is not a dictionary. how can I make it a dictionary?

also, i tried
            

            dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
            this does not work. why?

Comment: solved it:
dict = (from entry in dict orderby entry.Key ascending select entry).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);