# c# Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> order list by DateTime (nullable value)

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>>`

```
    Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> result =
        myList
            .GroupBy(k => new DateTime(k.Created.Value.Year, k.Created.Value.Month, 1))
            .OrderByDescending(k => k.Key)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
```

This will take a `List<Item>` groups it per year/month, order it descending (newest first) then creates a dictionary out of it.

My Question is: how can I OrderByDescending also the List within the Dictionary based on the the DateTime nullable (newest first)?

Comment: See that : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110324/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: First should be newest or first should be null?

Comment: First should be newest, there are no null values although is a nullable property. There will always be a datetime value.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> result = myList.GroupBy(k => new DateTime(k.Created.Value.Year, k.Created.Value.Month, 1))
  .OrderByDescending(k => k.Key)
  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.OrderByDescending(t => t.Published.GetValueOrDefault()).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<Item>> result =
    myList
        .GroupBy(k => new DateTime(k.Created.Value.Year, k.Created.Value.Month, 1))
        .OrderByDescending(k => k.Key)
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ToList());
```