# Sorting a dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to sort a dictonary by its key but all the other answers involved making a list and adding it to that. It there a way to sort the dictonary itself and move the keys along with the corresponding value? Example:

```
Dictonary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict.Add(0, 1);
dict.Add(5, 4);
dict.Add(2, 7);
dict.Add(7, 9);
dict.Add(1, 2);
dict.Add(4, 0);
```

then make the dictonary equal

0, 1

1, 2

2, 7

4, 0

5, 4

7, 9

Comment: Why not use SortedDictionary? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Dictionaries are HashTables, and thus unordered by definition

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Dictionary in place with respect to keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys)

Comment: Did one of the answers below give you what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by the dictionary being "equal" to what you said.  If it's just on output then

```
        foreach (var entry in dict)
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

will show

```
[0, 1]
[5, 4]
[2, 7]
[7, 9]
[1, 2]
[4, 0]
```

but

```
        foreach (var entry in new SortedDictionary<int, int>(dict)) // or SortedList
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
```

will show

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 7]
[4, 0]
[5, 4]
[7, 9]
```

The question of whether to choose SortedList or SortedDictionary is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary).