# Sorting two tables according to intersection

Tags: c#, sorting

I have two tables. I want to sort they like that intersection will be on the beginning.

```
1    9
5    6
6    10
10   5
```

I want to sort it to have:

```
5    5
6    6
10   10
1    9
```

This is simple example. In code I have two dictionaries to sort according to its keys.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the code you currently have.

Comment: Can you explain your reason for sorting the way you have? Why is 1 and 9 put together? Is this because they're not a pair? If so, then what happens with other values that don't have a match and how do you decide to sort those? Also, will both dictionaries have the same number of elements?

Comment: Right now I just generated two dictionaries and that's all. That's why I am asking. I don't have any idea how to sort it right now.

Comment: I need to show differences between two tables. I have table layout that I cannot change.

Comment: Worth looking at this as well if your going to use dictionaries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = new[] { 1, 5, 6, 10 };
var list2 = new[] { 9, 6, 10, 5 };
var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();

list1 = intersect.Union(list1).ToArray();
list2 = intersect.Union(list2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, very good idea. I have to write also comparer because I have dictionary of tuple<string,string> and I care only about keys in dictionary.