# c# dictionary<string,string> order by key asc empty value at the end

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` that contains keys and values.

There is one key which is null/empty.

How can I order the Dictionary by the key alphabetically and add the empty key at the bottom/end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Dictionary in place with respect to keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys)

Comment: Look at the marked answer [of this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys) it shown possible solutions with a different class and custom `IComparer`s. That sound exactly like what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) with custom [Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132246(v=vs.110).aspx). And sort it accordingly.

But like general advise: if the sort *does* matter to you, dictionary is not *usually* suitable data structure for handling that kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` doesn't have an order. Its backing store is a *hash table*. If you want to impose an order on it, use a [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx): its backing store is a *red-black tree* (height-balanced binary tree).

You should bear in mind that there are tradeoffs made WRT to memory usage, cost of insert/delete/lookup.

You might also need to provide a suitable comparer to impose the ordering you required.

If you need a comparer that compares null-high (most of the built-in ones are null-low), something like this should suffice:

```
public class MyCustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly StringComparer    baseComparer    ;
    private readonly StringComparison? comparisonStyle ;
    public MyCustomStringComparer( StringComparer baseComparer ) : this( baseComparer , null )
    {
    }
    public MyCustomStringComparer( StringComparison comparisonStyle ) : this( null , comparisonStyle )
    {
    }
    public MyCustomStringComparer() : this( null , null )
    {
    }
    private MyCustomStringComparer( StringComparer comparer , StringComparison? style )
    {
        this.baseComparer = comparer ;
        this.comparisonStyle = style ;
    }
    public int Compare( string x , string y )
    {
        if      ( x == null && y == null ) return  0 ; // two nulls are equal
        else if ( x == null && y != null ) return +1 ; // null is greater than non-null
        else if ( x != null && y == null ) return -1 ; // non-null is less than null
        else // ( x != null && y != null ) ;
        {
            if      ( baseComparer    != null ) return baseComparer.Compare(x,y);
            else if ( comparisonStyle != null ) return string.Compare(x,y,comparisonStyle.Value);
            else                                return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
}
```