# C# string Dictionary sorting

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to sort below dictionary by Key.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Numbers;
```

Sample data:

```
(100,+100)
(24,+24)
(214,+214)
(3,+3)
(1,+1)
```

Expected Output:

```
(1,+1)
(3,+3)
(24,+24)
(100,+100)
(214,+214)
```

If I use SortedDictionary, my output is

(1,+1)(100,+100)(24,+24)(214,+214)(3,+3)

Comment: Could you use a SortedDictionary instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I use SortedDictionary<string, string> . My output is (1,+1)(100,+100)(24,+24)(214,+214)(3,+3)

Comment: Have you given any thought to LINQ ?

Comment: Just for completeness, the reason the sorted dictionary didn't work is because you have a string for the key value.  The sort order is correct for a string sort.  By using @gaemaf answer you are indicating that the key can be an int value.  Your best course of action is to change Numbers to Numbers<int, string> and have the key be an integer everywhere. And just to be pedantic, the sort dictionary result with a string key is (1, +1)(100, +100)(214, +214)(24, +24)(3, +3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SortedDictionary but you need to rearrange your input or preserve your type:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Numbers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
  {"100","+100"},
  {"24","+24"},
  {"214","+214"},
  {"3","+3"},
  {"1","+1"}};

Numbers = Numbers.OrderBy(key => int.Parse(key.Key)).ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);

SortedDictionary<int, string> Numbers1 = new SortedDictionary<int, string> {
  {100,"+100"},
  {24,"+24"},
  {214,"+214"},
  {3,"+3"},
  {1,"+1"}};
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary type is inherently unordered, but you can use a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead.

A similar question was answered in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705623/2608569