# How can I sort a dictionary by an array?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, itext

I get the PDF metadatas using itextsharp as follows:

```
var pdf = new PdfReader(__PDF_PATH__);
var main = new[] { "Title", "Subject", "Creator", "Author", "Producer", "Keywords", "ModDate", "CreationDate" };
var metadatas = pdf.Info; // returns Dictionary<string, string> metadatas
```

The keys of the dictionary are as in the `main` array. I want to sort the dictionary's keys according to the given `main` array. But I did not manage.

Comment: A `Dictionary` has no internal order, hence you can't sort it. See also the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your `metadatas` dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at this answer here:
[Sorting a Dictionary in place with respect to keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705607/sorting-a-dictionary-in-place-with-respect-to-keys)

or you can look at this approach here:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary

but basically you cant do it in dictionary. you can convert to other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As other folks have mentioned, a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) has no order, and you can't sort it.

Depending on what you want to do with your `metadatas` dictionary, you could use your `main` array to copy the data into a different data structure, such as a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1), a [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1), or a `List<List<string>`.